# Is there a way to get a list of disabled/enabled network interfaces in C#

Tags: c#, network-programming, network-interface

I am programming a little script to change the IPv4 address of a specific Wireless80211 or Ethernet network interface. So far everything is working fine. The script sets the IPv4 with the command prompt and netsh (to control it with C# I use `System.Diagnostics`).
I want to add the feature, that the script disables or enables all Wireless80211 and Ethernet network interfaces (without a specific one) which you can find in "Control Panel>Network and Internet>Network Connections".

The script is mainly used for ArtNet to DMX to automatically prepare everything to use ArtNet (for people, which do not know anything of the Control Panel and to automate the workflow).
I have already tried it with the `System.Net.NetworkInformation` namespace, but I have only found a way to get enabled network interfaces. As soon as I disable an interface `System.Net.NetworkInformation` does not show this interface.

Comment: Do you mean equivalent to IPCONFIG/ALL?  See : https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/370616/Details-from-any-DOS-based-application

Comment: @jdweng yes and no. ipconfig /all shows exactly what I need. But if I deactivate a network interface, then this interface is no longer showen in the list from ipconfig /all

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wasn't aware that NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces() didn't return disabled interfaces.

Anyway, you could try using the WMI api via `System.Management.dll` that's available in the .NET framework (you must add this reference to your project), I did a test and it allows you to interact even with disabled network interfaces.

The following example give you an idea of how to work with WMI via this api, I pretty much extracted it from the documentation:

```
using System;
using System.Management;
...
void ListNetworkAdapters()
{
    var query = new ObjectQuery("SELECT * FROM Win32_NetworkAdapter");

    using (var searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(query))
    {
        var queryCollection = searcher.Get();

        foreach (var m in queryCollection)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("ServiceName : {0}", m["Name"]);
            Console.WriteLine("MACAddress : {0}", m["Description"]);
            Console.WriteLine();
        }

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

The documentation can be found here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/cimwin32prov/win32-networkadapter

Comment: Thank you very much for your fast help. Now the script works fine.

Answer (score 0):

NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces()

Then check the OperationalStatus property

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.networkinformation.networkinterface?view=netframework-4.7.2

Comment: `NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces()` does not show any deactivated network interface.